# Display min, max and distinct in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

For simplicity's sake, lets say I have a dataset that consists of several columns, and one column specifically is "year", with every row in that column being a different year from say 1850 to 2000, but there are many duplicates of rows, e.g. 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1853, 1853 ..... until 2000.

What I want to achieve is essentially:

SELECT min(year), max(year), count(distinct year)
from dataset;

but of course in NoSQL. Expected output would be one row with three columns, being min(year), max(year), and count(year), with the values being 1850, 2000, and 151 respectively.

I'm guessing this is extremely simple but I can't seem to get it. Thank you!

```
db.database.aggregate([ 
    {$group: {"_id":{},
        "min(year)": {"$min": "$year"}, 
        "max(year)": {"$max": "$year"},
```

Obtained the front output of min and max year, but can't seem to add the output of number of distinct years.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: In `"$group"` you could add a new field, `"distinctYears": {"$addToSet": "$year"}` and then in the next stage, `"$set": {"yearCount": {"$size": "$distinctYears"}, "distinctYears": "$$REMOVE"}`.

Comment: If you write a good answer below, I'll upvote it.